# How to override default location of snackbar notification DropZoneArea

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dropzone

I'm trying to change the default location of the snackbar in material ui [DropZone](https://yuvaleros.github.io/material-ui-dropzone/) to be at the bottom center.
The default location for the snackbar notification in vertical origin is **Bottom** and in the horizontal origin is **Left**. [image: SnackBar Notification Sample]

Any suggestions or thoughts would be helpful.

```
import React from "react";
import { DropzoneArea } from "material-ui-dropzone";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  dropZoneContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    minHeight: "0",
  },
}));

const DropZone = ({ text, onChange, error }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const SUPPORTED_FORMATS = [
    "image/jpg",
    "image/jpeg",
    "image/gif",
    "image/png",
  ];
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <DropzoneArea
        acceptedFiles={SUPPORTED_FORMATS}
        maxFileSize={2000000}
        useChipsForPreview
        filesLimit={1}
        dropzoneText={text}
        onChange={onChange}
        classes={{ root: classes.dropZoneContainer }}
      />
      <label style={{ color: "black", fontSize: "0.9rem" }}>
        Max size allowed is 2 MB
      </label>
      <small
        className="form-text text-danger"
        style={{ color: "red", fontSize: "0.8rem", fontWeight: "bold" }}
      >
        {error}
      </small>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default DropZone;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `alertSnackbarProps` to pass props to the SnackBar within`DropzoneArea`.

Use the `anchorOrigin` prop to position `Snackbar`

like

```
  <DropzoneArea
    acceptedFiles={SUPPORTED_FORMATS}
    maxFileSize={2000000}
    useChipsForPreview
    filesLimit={1}
    dropzoneText={text}
    onChange={onChange}
    classes={{ root: classes.dropZoneContainer }}
    alertSnackbarProps={{anchorOrigin:{ vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'center' }}}
  />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Invalid syntax.

Comment: need to pass an object to alertSnackbarProps, fixed